# Spacemacs - How to open shell in a separate window?

Tags: spacemacs

Is it possible to launch shell in Spacemacs like a separate window beside my main window with code?

I would like to use it for various tasks like running tests, tools and apps etc

I mainly plan to use it for Python coding so any Python-specific tips are also very welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think part of what you're looking for is found in the [Shell layer](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+tools/shell/README.html#install), this will let you do anything you'd ordinarily do in a terminal emulator, you could launch iPython or the like from here.

Once the layer is installed you can use the following [key bindings](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+tools/shell/README.html#key-bindings):

```
|-------------+------------------------------------------------------|
| Key binding | Description                                          |
|-------------+------------------------------------------------------|
| SPC '​       | Open, close or go to the default shell               |
| SPC "​       | Open external terminal emulator in current directory |
| SPC p '​     | Open a shell in the project's root                   |
| SPC p "​     | Open external terminal emulator in project root      |
| TAB         | browse completion with `helm`                        |
| SPC m H     | browse history with helm (works in eshell and shell) |
| C-j         | next item in history                                 |
| C-k         | previous item in history                             |
|-------------+------------------------------------------------------|
```

The other part is in the [Python layer](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/python/README.html) which supports spawning a python interpreter, this can by launched by `SPC m s i`.

If you like Jupyter Notebook (formerly iPython notebook) there's a layer for that too (ipython-notebook), once installed you can launch it with `SPC a i n`.